# Событие MouseWheel формы, Windows Form

Tags: winforms

Мне нужно, чтобы при прокрутке колесика мыши изменялась прозрачность формы. Но я не очень понимаю, как в коде прописать это событие. Получается прописать его для какого-нибудь объекта, например picturebox, а вот для самой формы непонятно как!

Answer (score 1):

Вот долго думала, а как только задала вопрос - сразу же нашла решение. :)

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.MouseWheel += Form1_MouseWheel;
        }

        private void Form1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
           //код      
        }
```